# Can't click button when using Thread.Sleep in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

First, I want to check if my object is null. It will sleep 20 milliseconds in while loop gives user can be interactive with UI.

If the condition in while is correct, I can click the button in UI to break this loop and continues other code.

I tried with by original code:

```
while (browser.FindElementById("iframe") == null)
{
    if(buttonWasClicked == true)
        return;
    Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

I was tried with:

```
Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => 
{
    while (browser.FindElementById("iframe") == null)
    {
        if(buttonWasClicked == true)
            return;
    }
});
```

Seem block code working in the background. So, it skips block code and executes all next line code.

I want it must check before executing next code.

So, I tried with another method. I using `Timer` but I don't usually use `Timer` in the application, I don't have any experience with this.

I created new `Timer` like `timer1` and set `interval = 20`.

At `timer1_Tick` event, I add code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (browser.FindElementById("iframe") == null)
    {
        if(buttonWasClicked == true)
            break;
    }
    else
        timer1.Stop();
}
```

And at original code, I replace with:

`timer1.Start();`

At `button_Clicked` event, I set to:

`timer1.Stop();`.

Have any issues with my code?

In debug, it skip event `timer1_Tick()` and execute all code after line `timer.Start()`.

Comment: There is only a single UI thread in .NET which does all the UI handling. If you freeze it by sleeping, you won't be able to process events and the UI will appear unresponsive. Next, the WinForms `Timer` you added also fires the event on the UI thread, and you again shouldn't sleep inside the handler.

Comment: @Groo I found two methods to do this. Using `Timer` or `BackgroundWorker`. But `BackgroundWorker` seem not suited for my scenario.

Comment: `timer1.Start()` will not block the thread, it will just tell the timer to fire the event after the 20ms interval. The code after `timer.Start()` will continue executing. So, while it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish, I am presuming all code after `timer.Start()` should actually execute when you find the `iframe`? Then simply move this code into a different method and call it from the timer handler once you find the `iframe`.

Comment: @Groo Yes, all code should execute after find `iframe`. At time can't found `iframe` it should wait to user interactive with an application; specifically, the user clicks a button. Move code to another method really resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "wait for button push" code is in the GUI thread, this looks like an good use for `await`.  Consider creating an awaitable event ([manual](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/) or [auto](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/)) and using that instead of `buttonWasClicked`.  You main code would then look like:

```
evtButtonClicked = new AsyncManualResetEvent();

await evtButtonClicked.WaitAsync();

// continuation code...
```

Now, when you call evtButtonClicked.Set(), the continuation code will be queued up to execute on the GUI thread.  Recall that the code after `await` is effectively wrapped into a `Task.ContinueWith()`, which means that your GUI thread will not block while waiting for the event.